# Install php5-mcrypt on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, mcrypt

I want to install the mcrypt on vagrant machine.

The OS is Ubuntu.

Which is the command?

Comment: ``sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt``

Comment: I try it before. `Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 8):

First check php version,

E.g.

```
php -v
```

PHP 5.6.38-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)

Currently php version is 5.6, you will need to install with below command line

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoqaO.png)

Comment: I'm so confused that I can't install php mycript but then I realise that I probably follow a decayed tutorial that guide me to install it with "php5_mcrypt" command. I just miss the detail version. Thank you so much

Comment: Is this still applicable.

Comment: As I checked, it worked.